# Spreading data across two subplots with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create two subplots that display a large amount of data from a dataframe. This is just one x axis but results in many column and due to this it does not display correctly over one plot. I therefore am trying to get one subplot displaying the first 25 columns and the 2nd subplot the next 25 for example. I can create one plot fine, I can create two identical plots fine but cant do what I am trying to achieve.

I have tried a number of different ways such as this:

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
if score <= 100000:
    ax1.plot(score)
else:
    ax2.plot(score)
```

The above may be completely wrong but when I try this I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I feel like there should be an easy way to do this but I just cant figure it out.

Comment: how does score look like?

Comment: Hey, it is unclear if `score` is a DataFrame or an array or a scalar value. The problem doesn't seem to be difficult after all but you might have problems with slicing perhaps in pandas?

Comment: Score probably works out at about 100 different lines ranging in values. If I could just split these line in half that would be perfect. I have a line where I add individual scores in the scores column to get score and if I hover on score it says it is a series: score = df['Scores'].value_counts()

Answer (score 0):

You can simply slice your *pandas*' 'DataFrame'-object (remember that indices need to be of type integer => cast it):

```py
df[0:int(len(df)/2)]
```

so you get:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# create dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=['Col 1','Col 2','Col 4','Col 5'])
# open figure
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
#plot 1st half [0:50]
axs[0].plot( df[0:int(len(df)/2)] )
#plot 2nd half [50:100]
axs[1].plot( df[int(len(df)/2): ] )
```

[image]